# How to exclude dependencies from Gradle Version Catalog?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I'd like to perform the equivalent to the following declaration:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4') {
        exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
    }
}
```

But within the version catalog feature. Something like:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            library('commons-lang3', 'org.apache.commons', 'commons-lang3').exclude {
                // group, module etc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From a comment on a somewhat unrelated issue:

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/19517#issuecomment-1012159205

> (...) the catalog is purely a list of dependencies to pick from.

So, anything else such as exclusions, you must define them as usual in the `dependencies { }` block.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to do this, which unfortunately isn't documented:

```
implementation dependencies.create(libs.commons.beanutils.get()) {
    exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
}
```

Note the `get()` call - beanutils in this case is an instance of `Provider<?>` so you need to manually unwrap it.

Comment: this results in "Cannot convert the provided notation to an object of type Dependency" for me

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty ugly but works

in kotlin for example:

```
vorbisspi = "com.googlecode.soundlibs:vorbisspi:1.0.3.3"
```

```kotlin
implementation(libs.mp3spi.get().let { "${it.module}:${it.versionConstraint.requiredVersion}" }) {
    exclude("javazoom.spi", "spi")
    exclude("junit", "junit")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In libs.versions.toml file

```
[versions] 
retrofitCoroutinesAdapter = "0.9.2"
```

In build.gradle(app) file

```
implementation dependencies.create(libs.retrofitCoroutinesAdapter.get()) {
exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx'
}
```